# Converting paging function to a Flow

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I have a large quantity of sqlite databases, represented as `Source[File, NotUsed]`. For each db, I want to paginate through the results. Memory limits mean I cannot do this eagerly. Say that the result type is `Foo`, then I'm trying to figure out how to create a `Flow[File, Foo, NotUsed]` that internally uses a lazy, recursive call on the resource.

I see that the `Source.unfold` method allows me to do this, but it can only create a `Source`, which means I can't feed it the necessary input of `File`. I can't see how to convert a `Source` to a `Flow` (except via [fromSinkAndSource](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.13/stream/operators/Flow/fromSinkAndSource.html), but that doesn't pipe the values through). I'm not sure if this path of inquiry will yield anything.

It was suggested to me that I should use the `GraphDSL` and `Merge`, but I'm stuck trying to understand how many input ports the `Merge` should have and how I would actually wire it together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the [`flatMapConcat`](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/flatMapConcat.html) operator:

> ### Signature
>
> ```
> def flatMapConcat[T, M](f: Out ⇒ Graph[SourceShape[T], M]): Repr[T]
> ```
>
> ### Description
>
> Transform each input element into a `Source` whose elements are then flattened into the output stream through concatenation. This means each source is fully consumed before consumption of the next source starts.
>
> **emits** when the current consumed substream has an element available
>
> **backpressures** when downstream backpressures
>
> **completes** when upstream completes and all consumed substreams complete